# Q: ReactNative StackNavigator inside DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

is there any good no bugs example with StackNavigator inside DrawerNavigator?
As in my example when the drawer is open the top Navigation title is hidden and I can't open the drawer(with slide) when I am inside the NewScreen page.
So I want to open the drawer over the title and from any page.
Thanks

http://image.prntscr.com/image/eb4d869acbcf4d22a08159b072aae930.png

Here is the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    Button,
    Platform,
    ScrollView,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableHighlight,
    Text,
} from 'react-native';
import {
    DrawerNavigator,StackNavigator
} from 'react-navigation';

import FontAwesome from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";

class ScreenHome extends Component{
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'ScreenHome',
    };
    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <Button
                title="Go to Jane's profile"
                onPress={() => navigate('New', { name: 'Jane' })}
            />
        );
    }
}

class NewScreen extends Component{
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'New screen',
    };
    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <Text>Some new screen</Text>
        );
    }
}

class ScreenRegister extends Component{
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'ScreenRegister',
    };
    render(){
        return <Text>ScreenRegister</Text>
    }
}

const MainScreenNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
    Recent: {
        screen: ScreenHome
    },
    All: {
        screen: ScreenRegister
    },
});

export default SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: MainScreenNavigator
    },
    Chat: {
        screen: ScreenHome
    },
    New: {
        screen: NewScreen
    }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('naviTest', () => SimpleApp);
```

Comment: [Looks to be an open issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/165). You should check out the comments for possible workarounds, though after reading through all of them, it looks like each solution has some sort of bug in it.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your questions correctly, you want:

1) To have access to the drawer from any page

2) Your drawer to cover the title bar when open.

**To achieve Number 1**

There are two ways you can do it and they are:
a) Add a button/Icon that triggers the drawer on click. When you use this solution, you will still not have the slide from left functionality as this is controlled explicitly by the DrawerNavigator 
b) Add NewScreen to your Drawer since you want to have access to the entire drawer when you are within the screen

**To achieve Number 2**

This is a very common issue when nesting DrawerNavigator within StackNavigator. To resolve this, modify StackNavigator thus

```
export default SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: MainScreenNavigator
    },
    Chat: {
        screen: ScreenHome
    },
    New: {
        screen: NewScreen
    }
},  {
    navigationOptions: { header:  false  }
});
```